# Get embed link of custom type by slug?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is it possible to query the embed link of a specific post or post type? For my API call, I originally used a link like this to get img URLS:

`http://myprivateblogapi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/case_studies?_embed`,

but now as I'm using a dynamic query to render data, I'm using a link like this

`http://myprivateblogapi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/case_studies/?slug=${csVariable}`

I'd rather get the embeddable link if I can, to get image URLs and author information, just so that I can make one call instead of two. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible :)

Try something like this :

```
http://myprivateblogapi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/case_studies?_embed&slug=your-slug-here
```